# Setting up tf for Hector SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, hokuyo-node, hector-slam, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

I am trying to get my hokuyo laser node to work with hector_slam to produce realtime SLAM. I have installed hokuyo_node and the laser seems working properly. I also completed the hector_slam tutorial using the "Team_Hector_..bag" file. However, when I rosrun hokuyo_node and hector_slam(through a launch file), I just can't get it right. My launch file settings are as follows:

Then I went back to rerun the hector_slam tutorial, I use rxgraph to check what the nodes/topics are. Then, I found that a "/play node" (play back of the *.bag file in the tutorial) publish a '/tf' topic and "/hector_mapping" node subscribe to it. If I just rosrun hokuyo_node, then the "/hokuyo_node" just publish the '/scan' topic. I guess the problem is here. Can anyone elaborate a little more on this '/tf' and how to resolve it when using real laser scanners? THANKS A LOT.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40414/setting-up-tf-for-hector-slam/) by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Messi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5076/messi/) on 2013-06-08**:
please share your launch file, i have a same problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the problem is related to tf not being available. To get an overview of how tf works you can have a look at the following links:

[TF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials)

[Hector SLAM setup tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)

The easiest option to make it work is manually starting a tf publisher that publishes the needed transform from the base_link that you want to have localized to the laser scanner frame. This can be done by adding the following to a launch file:

```
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 50" />
```

/edit: This is assuming you have set the hector_mapping parameters like this:

```
  <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
  <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
  <param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
  <param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1